# PHP json_encode gapi (google analytics) array returns empty values

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, json

I am using the gapi class in a CodeIgniter website. I am using this implementation:

http://jjc.net/2011/google-analytics-api-for-codeigniter/

This returns an array which works perfectly. I want to pass it to my js and I am doing this like so:

```
$gapi_arr = array();
$gapi_arr = $this->gapi->requestReportData($report_id, array('date'), array('pageviews', 'visits', 'newVisits'), 'date', '', $start_date, $end_date, 1, 366);

echo json_encode($gapi_arr);
```

However this returns:

```
[{},{},{},{},{}...
```

The original array that the gapi class returns looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => gapiReportEntry Object
    (
        [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
            (
                [pageviews] => 3
                [visits] => 3
                [newVisits] => 0
            )

        [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20110101
            )

    )

[1] => ...
```

I just want to pass this array to my js without writing inline js code in my views. Is there a fix or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The given array is not an array at all, look at the "gapiReportEntry", this is an Object. You should first iterate through all and convert to primitives.

Comment: Ok, didn't think that mattered since it is an array of objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) can process object just fine, however, all the properties in the gapiReportEntry object are **private**  and [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) only shows the **public** properties.

This explains all the empty objects `{}` in the json-array.

Answer (score 1):

Change the PRIVATE by PUBLIC in gapi.php

```
class gapiReportEntry
    {
      public $metrics = array();
      public $dimensions = array();
      ....
```

DOne!

Answer (score 0):

json_encode knows how to handle primatives, numeric index arrays and associative arrays.  This is none of the above.